# Reference doc for webhook

Tags: botframework

I searched all the documentation on https://docs.botframework.com and couldn't find where is the documentation of what can be received on Messaging Endpoint defined in the Bot Administration.

```
{
    "text": "yop",
    "type": "message",
    "timestamp": "2017-03-01T07:37:38.509Z",
    "id": "1488353858503",
    "channelId": "skype",
    "serviceUrl": "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/apis/",
    "from": {
        "id": "a",
        "name": "never ever"
    },
    "conversation": {
        "id": "a"
    },
    "recipient": {
        "id": "b",
        "name": "name"
    },
    "entities": [
        {
            "locale": "en-US",
            "platform": "Windows",
            "type": "clientInfo"
        }
    ]
}
```

E.g. what are all the message types. Did any of you find this documentation? Please post a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the following [documentation of the enumeration class](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/d2/d7d/class_microsoft_1_1_bot_1_1_connector_1_1_activity_types.html) that contains all the possible `types`. Also the [source code of the class](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/d9/da2/_activity_types_8cs_source.html) itself.

The class hierarchy can be seen here;
[image: --]

Where [IActivity](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/de/d19/interface_microsoft_1_1_bot_1_1_connector_1_1_i_activity.html#a20e224c1ab869ab4ec0338de9ea896c3) interface looks like the entity you've shared, I found the type field with the above enum class in the implementer of that interface. It looks like the enum class is used in this [ActivityEx](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/d7/da4/_activity_ex_8cs_source.html) class, but the name suggests that it might be deprecated, and currently [Activity](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/dc/d2f/class_microsoft_1_1_bot_1_1_connector_1_1_activity.html) class is used, though its `type` field is still type `String`. I'd assume the enum contains all the values of `type`, but there might be more. I hope this information was useful!

Comment: Thx, @bureaquete,  the bounty is yours as it helps to clarify some things. I won't accept the answer though as it's language specific. (If somebody things it shall be accepted just write me your opinion.)

Comment: @zatziky Glad that the information was helpful, but even though I shared the source code the important thing was the enumeration data that you wanted, also I shared the documentation of those classes, so the language shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

I've found some description right in the tutorial:

https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/core-concepts/messages/#navtitle

[image]